# Unable to update close date on vf page in Salesforce1 and desktop

Tags: apex, visualforce

Created a VF page to show the close date of opportunity. I am not able to update  any other date.

When I am trying to enter some other date it is not taking any other date and when saved it is giving the below error in Desktop as well as in Salesforce1.

**Close Date: You must enter a value**

**Here is my VF Page code:**

```
<style> <!-- **I don't want date picker onload that's why I am using this style** -->
 .datePicker{
             visibility:hidden;
                 }
</style>

<tr>
<td>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}" type="date" />
</td>
<td><apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Probably your opportunity has as required another date field that you are not showing in your custom VF. Check the object to see if there is another Date required...

Comment: @MANUELAN00 No, I was able to update that field if I remove type = "date". But what happening is the date Picker on Mobile format is very bad.

Answer (score 0):

When you use **apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"** Salesforce will render the field according to the data type, if is a text it will show it as text area, if is a date it will show you a standard date picker, there is no need to specify type="date" like in a normal input tag.

If you want to show your own datepicker style (bypass the standard functionality, which I don't recommend as you will lose some features), you can achieve that in this way:

```
  <apex:inputHidden id="inputDATE" value=" {!objOrder.Required_Date__c}" />           
  <input class="form-control" type="text" id="datepicker"/>
        <script>
        $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy' });
        if(document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value != null){
        var obj = document.getElementById('{!$Component.mainform.inputDATE}').value;
        $( "#datepicker" ).val(obj);
        }
        });                                     
        </script>
```

In my opinion you should only use **apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"**, in this way you will keep the standard functionality across all devices.

```
<tr>
<td>
<apex:inputField value="{!opportunity.CloseDate}"/>
</td>
<td><apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="save" />
</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: @MANUELANOO Thanks for providing the answer will try the solution you provided

Comment: Don't forget to mark it as a best answer if solves your question :)...